# Understanding matrix algebra equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coordinate-systems

I'm currently reading through a journal online and I came across this particular mathematical equation:

$\Vert{a} - Tb - k \Vert_2 \leq \beta$

$a = [x,y]'$, T = $\begin{bmatrix}f & h\\e & z\end{bmatrix}$, b = [x,y]' and k = [g,h]

Basically, $a$ and $b$ are coordinates, T is a matrix of numbers and k is the difference in x,y coordinates of $a$ and $b$.

Particularly, I do not understand what does the $\Vert \Vert_2$ means. Could anyone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ denotes the euclidean norm,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)